# Why blurOnSubmit={false} can't work in TextInput

Tags: react-native

```js
<TextInput
style={{
  paddingHorizontal: 10,
  width: 230,
}}
onFocus={handleTextInputFocus}
value={text}
onChangeText={setText}
returnKeyType='none'
onSubmitEditing={sendMessage}
blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

const sendMessage = async () => {
    let temp = text;
    setText('');
    // scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    try {
      const data = await FetchFromBackend(
        'http://192.168.31.119:8080/message/send_group_messages',
        SendGroupMessagesRequest({ user_id, group_id, text: temp })
      );
      if (data.data.ActionStatus === 'FAIL') {
        console.error(`send message fail: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`send message success: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    getMessages();
  };
```

Why TextInput can't focus after submiting? I have already added `blurOnSubmit={false}`. I also use useRef focus function to implement it. However, it still can't work.
Any help would be really amazing thank you